# Select a predefined string if a column contains a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID  Column a Column b
-- --------- --------
1   1           a
2   0           b
3   1           c
```

The `Column a` is a bit type.
What I want to achieve given an ID is something like this:

```
@Id = 1 -> a, 'Hello' 
@Id = 2 -> b, ''      
@Id = 3 -> c, 'Hello'
```

I have tried to do it with an IF and ELSE statement without result. I think that i don't understand how the IF and ELSE works in SQL.
What I have tried:

```
SELECT Column b
       ,IF(Column a = 1) SELECT 'Hello' ELSE SELECT ''
FROM Table where ID = @Id
```

In summary, I'm looking for a way to "print" a certain value depending on the value of a certain query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what CASE is for

```
SELECT
  b,
  CASE a
    WHEN 1 THEN 'HELLO'
    ELSE ''
  END
```

CASE has two forms:

```
CASE 
  WHEN boolean_test THEN result
  WHEN other_boolean_test THEN other_result --optional
  ...  --more WHENs, optional
  ELSE --optional
END
```

And

```
CASE x
  WHEN value_to_compare_to_x THEN result
  WHEN other_value_to_compare_to_x  THEN other_result --optional
  ... --more WHENs, optional
  ELSE --optional
END
```

Either will work, but for decoding a single column, I find `CASE column WHEN value THEN result` form neater. Note though that you can't use complex expressions in this form, e.g. `CASE x WHEN IN(1,2,3) THEN ..` is not allowed; you have to use `CASE WHEN x IN(1,2,3) THEN..`

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [CASE expression.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

```
Select [Column B], CASE 
    WHEN [Column a] = 1 
    THEN 'Hello' 
    ELSE '' END
FROM Table where ID = @Id
```

This can also be used with more than 1 condition

```
Select [Column B], CASE 
    WHEN [Column a] = 1 
    THEN 'Hello' 
    WHEN [Column a] IS NULL  
    THEN 'Goodbye' 
    ELSE '' END
FROM Table where ID = @Id
```